# Profiler calls function without providing true arguments

Tags: workbench

I found Profile[] in the Mathematica workbench does not run on my function. To investigate, I provided a simple function,

```
In[]:= test[arg_] := (Print[arg]);

In[]:= Profile[test[1]]
Out[]= 
1
1
```

This is as expected, only that the profiler called the function twice. However, after running my code, if I run the same test function again, I get

```
In[]:= test[arg_] := (Print[arg]);

In[]:= Profile[test[1]]
Out[]= 
1
1
1
arg_
arg
```

Very strange that the profiler tries to call the function with arg_, instead of the given argument 1. And this is exactly the first error message I got when I use Profile to run my code.

EDIT: I created an empty project and the above simple example does not make a mistake. Thus the problem should be some part of my code is incompatible with the Profiler...

PS: my code is too long to be provided here. Just in case of an interest, it is at

https://github.com/tririver/MathGR/tree/experimental

```
<< MathGR/gr.m
Profile[Simp[t[DN@"a", DN@"a"]]]
```